# How to load model data to Select2 dropdown which uses Ajax filtering in Yii

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii, jquery-select2

I use the following select2 Yii widget in my view to populate a drop-down list. Since the data necessary for the preparation of the select list consists of more than 2K records I use select2 with minimumInputLength parameter and an ajax query to generate partial result of the list based on user input. If I create a new record I have no problem at all. It populates everything fine and I can save data to my database. However I don't know how to load saved data back to this drop-down during my update action. I read somewhere that initselection intended for this purpose but I couldn't figure out how to use it.

Can someone help me out on this?

My view:

```
$this->widget('ext.select2.ESelect2', array(
            'selector' => '#EtelOsszerendeles_osszetevo_id',
            'options'  => array(
                    'allowClear'=>true,
                    'placeholder'=>'Kérem válasszon összetevőt!',
                    'minimumInputLength' => 3,
                    'ajax' => array(
                            'url' => Yii::app()->createUrl('etelOsszerendeles/filterOsszetevo'),
                            'dataType' => 'json',
                            'quietMillis'=> 100,
                            'data' => 'js: function(text,page) {
                                            return {
                                                q: text,
                                                page_limit: 10,
                                                page: page,
                                            };
                                        }',
                            'results'=>'js:function(data,page) { var more = (page * 10) < data.total; return {results: data, more:more }; }',
                    ),
            ),
          ));?>
```

My controller's action filter:

```
public function actionFilterOsszetevo()
{
    $list = EtelOsszetevo::model()->findAll('nev like :osszetevo_neve',array(':osszetevo_neve'=>"%".$_GET['q']."%"));
    $result = array();
    foreach ($list as $item){
        $result[] = array(
                'id'=>$item->id,
                'text'=>$item->nev,
        );
    }
    echo CJSON::encode($result);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use initSelection to load existing record for update in this way (I replaced some of your view code with `...` to focus in main changes). Tested with Yii 1.1.14. Essentially, I use two different ajax calls:

View:

```
<?php

$this->widget('ext.select2.ESelect2', array(
        'selector' => '#EtelOsszerendeles_osszetevo_id',
        'options'  => array(
                ...
                ...
                'ajax' => array(
                        'url' => Yii::app()->createUrl('client/searchByQuery'),
                        ...
                        ...
                        'data' => 'js: function(text,page) {
                                        return {
                                            q: text,
                                            ...
                                        };
                                    }',
                        ...
                ),
                'initSelection'=>'js:function(element,callback) {
                   var id=$(element).val(); // read #selector value
                   if ( id !== "" ) {
                     $.ajax("'.Yii::app()->createUrl('client/searchById').'", {
                       data: { id: id },
                       dataType: "json"
                     }).done(function(data,textStatus, jqXHR) { callback(data[0]); });
                   }
                }',
        ),
      ));
?>
```

Now in your controller you should receive parameters for ajax processing: query (q), as string, when inserting; id (id) as int when updating. Parameter names must be same as ajax `data` parameters (in this sample insert `q`; in update `id`) when read in $_GET. Code is not refactored/optimized:

Controller:

```
 public function actionSearchByQuery(){
        $data = Client::model()->searchByQuery( (string)$_GET['q'] );
        $result = array();
        foreach($data as $item):
           $result[] = array(
               'id'   => $item->id,
               'text' => $item->name,
           );
        endforeach;
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo CJSON::encode( $result );
        Yii::app()->end(); 
 }

 public function actionSearchById(){
        $data = Client::model()->findByPk( (int) $_GET['id'] );
        $result = array();
        foreach($data as $item):
           $result[] = array(
               'id'   => $item->id,
               'text' => $item->name,
           );
        endforeach;
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo CJSON::encode( $result );
        Yii::app()->end(); 
 }
```

Model - custom query and a little of order / security / clean :)

```
 public function searchByQuery( $query='' ) {
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria->select    = 'id, ssn, full_name';
        $criteria->condition = "ssn LIKE :ssn OR full_name LIKE :full_name";
        $criteria->params = array (
            ':ssn' => '%'. $query .'%',
            ':full_name' => '%'. $query .'%',
        );
        $criteria->limit = 10;
        return $this->findAll( $criteria );
 }
```

**EDIT:**

It works out of box when update is preloaded with traditional HTTP Post (synchronous, for example with Yii generated forms). For async/Ajax  updates, for example with JQuery:

Event / Trigger:

```
$('#button').on("click", function(e) {
        ...  
        ... your update logic, ajax request, read values, etc
        ...
        $('#select2_element').select2('val', id_to_load );
});
```

With this, `initSelection` will run again in async way with new `id_to_load` value, reloading record by id.

In your case and for your needs, `initSelection` could be complete different to avoid load record from db or [you can use  `formatResult` and `formatSelection` custom functions (are described in Load Remote Data sample source code)](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#documentation). Reading documentation, I understand that initSelection's callback need JSON data with id and text elements to load properly or you could try to combine both concepts (this initSelection with your custom JS event/trigger call)  (not tested):

```
       'initSelection'=>'js:function(element,callback) {
                   // here your code to load and build your values,
                   // this is very basic sample 
                   var id='myId'; 
                   var text='myValue'; 
                   data = {
                     "id": id,
                     "text": text
                   }
                   callback(data);                       
        }',
```

Or directly on Trigger call:

```
$('#button').on("click", function(e) {
        ...  
        ...             ...
        $("#select2_element").select2("data", {id: "myId", text: "MyVal"});
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Alejandro! I'll give it a try and get back to you soon.

Comment: I'm playing around with this but I need some explanation on the initSelection part. Actually my filter action for initSelection grabs all required information from the url, thus I don't have to pass any data to it. I think this is what first part of your code does in initSelection. So once I push the update button and my update action starts, filter controller can return the selected id and value. So, how can I pass it to my select2 widget to function as init value?

Comment: @g0m3z Hi, please review EDIT section, I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me out! I solved the problem based on your valuable comment, which helped me to understand how initSelection works. What I did wrong at the first try was that I included `initSelection` into the ajax definition. After I moved it to the proper place it worked fine. I used the following code to load values once update action called : `initSelection'=>'js:function(element,callback){var data={id:'.$model->osszetevo->id.',text:"'.$model->osszetevo->nev.'"}; callback(data);}',`

Answer (score 0):

I tried doing that way, but couldn't do it

the solution I came up to get my record filled and selected was:

In case of the attribute having some data(in update mode or default value), I wrote some javascript that after document ready event, would fill the select with my data (just selected it ind pushed html in it), and made it selected,  and then I rest( or update) the select to show my work.