# select2 extension, update the selected value

Tags: php, jquery, json, yii, jquery-select2

i am stuck at a point, please solve this mystery, I am using select2 extension fortunately it is a searchable drop down, like when i start typing, it loads the stored data from my `business` table. Just a query how can i show my selected business in update view, I am currently in address view, where there are four fields, `sector, city, business, street`. I am getting business name using select2 extension, it is working but when i update an address, every stored field's data comes up, except the business.
HERE is my code of address/views/_form

```
<?php
/* @var $this AddressController */
/* @var $model Address */
/* @var $form CActiveForm */
?>

<div class="form">

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.BsActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'address-form',
    // Please note: When you enable ajax validation, make sure the corresponding
    // controller action is handling ajax validation correctly.
    // There is a call to performAjaxValidation() commented in generated controller code.
    // See class documentation of CActiveForm for details on this.
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
)); ?>

    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

    <div class="row">

        <?php echo $form->textFieldControlGroup($model,'street_number',array('size'=>45,'maxlength'=>45)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'street_number'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'business_id'); ?>
         <?php

  $this->widget('ext.select2.ESelect2',array(
  'name'=>'Address[business_id]',
  'data'=>CHtml::listData(Business::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'business_name'), //the whole available list
  'htmlOptions'=>array(
       'placeholder'=>' search business name?',
    //'options'=>$options, //the selected values
    //'multiple'=>'multiple',
    'style'=>'width:530px',
  ),
  ));
    ?>
    </div>
       </br>

    <div class="row">

        <?php echo $form->textFieldControlGroup($model,'sector',array('size'=>45,'maxlength'=>45)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'sector'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

        <?php echo $form->textFieldControlGroup($model,'city',array('size'=>45,'maxlength'=>45)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'city'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo BsHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>
    </div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div><!-- form -->
```

How can i get the selected value(business) in update view??

Comment: Hope this help you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22972985/how-to-load-model-data-to-select2-dropdown-which-uses-ajax-filtering-in-yii/22979412#22979412

Comment: i already have visited that link, is there any way to solve this without ajax ? as i am not very well aware of ajax coding.

Comment: Yes, with initSelection you can customize how to load your select2. Javascript is required, ajax is optional

Comment: Please see my answer, hope it helps you

Comment: unfortunately i do not know javascript well, would you make it simple for me please? it is my project and i want to keep it as simple as possible.

Answer (score 1):

For single value, in your view and select2 definition and [select2 version <= 3.5.3](http://select2.github.io/select2/) we need to user initSelection function with Javascript/JQuery. From [select2 documentation](http://select2.github.io/select2/):

> ```
> Called when Select2 is created to allow the user to initialize the selection based on the value of the element select2 is attached to.
>
> Essentially this is an id->object mapping function.
>
> initSelection(element, callback)
>
> Parameter  Type         Description
>
> element    jQuery array Element Select2 is attached to.
> callback   function     Callback function that should be called with the data which is either an object in case of a single select or an array of objects in case of multi-select.
>
> This function will only be called when there is initial input to be processed.
> Here is an example implementation used for tags. Tags are the simplest form of data where the id is also the text:
> ```

```
$("#tags").select2({
    initSelection : function (element, callback) {
        var data = [];
        $(element.val().split(",")).each(function () {
            data.push({id: this, text: this});
        });
        callback(data);
    }
});

// Or for single select elements:
$("#select").select2({
    initSelection : function (element, callback) {
        var data = {id: element.val(), text: element.val()};
        callback(data);
    }
});
```

Now for Yii <= 1.x, with single select2 value, add `initSelection` function to your select2 definition in Yii required way:

```
echo $form->textField($model, 'business_id');
$this->widget('ext.select2.ESelect2',array(
    'options'=>array(
        //Html input for related model_id field
        'selector'=>'Address[business_id]',
        'data'=>CHtml::listData(Business::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'business_name'),
        'initSelection'=>'js:function(element,callback) {
               // here your code to load and build your values,
               // this is very basic sample. $model comes from 
               // your yii Controller
               var id='.$model->business_id.'; 
               var text='.$model->business_name.'; 
               data = {
                 "id": id,
                 "text": text
               }
               callback(data);                       
        }',
      ),
    ));
```

With multiselect:

```
echo $form->textField($model, 'business_id');

$this->widget('ext.select2.ESelect2',array(
    'options'=>array(
    //In $model->business_id, you must first to load values in 
    //in format: 1,4,6,7,8. You can perform this on controller or
    //model
        'selector'=>'Address[business_id]',
        'data'=>CHtml::listData(Business::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'business_name'),

        'multiple'=>'multiple',
        'initSelection'=>'js:function(element,callback) {
             //$dataMultiselect, loaded from controller or model
             callback('.$dataMultiSelect.');
        }',
    ),
));
```

How to load $dataMultiSelect. Example reading a dataset in controller. You need to fill $dataMultiSelect with JSON object: `id,text`  required by `initSelection`:

```
$dataMultiSelect = array();
foreach($listRelatedData as $relatedData):
    $dataMultiSelect[] = array(
                   'id'=>$relatedData->id, 
                   'text'=>$relatedData->description);
endforeach;
...
...
$this->render('update', array(
                'model' => $model,
                'dataMultiSelect' => CJSON::encode($dataMultiSelect)
  ));
```